# API to tell me if the video is YouTube originals

Tags: youtube

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell me if a video is YouTube originals or not through YouTube data API, analytics API or any other APIs?

I've looked through the data API and analytics API documents but did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/f89222305113c96ab03d63621f8140d4c9a801c6#diff-515c409ddb619da28c52829262e517f3d2ab4910aaa2ab60dd88e9064e0cfd4fR228-R233) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=isOriginal&id=VIDEO_ID, you will get whether or not the given video is a YouTube original in `item["isOriginal"]`.

[The YouTube video `iqKdEhx-dD4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqKdEhx-dD4) is a YouTube original. With this video id you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "iqKdEhx-dD4",
            "isOriginal": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try the youtube operational API.

Comment: Yl3N9dQlHw4 is also a youtube originals video, but
https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=isOriginal&id=Yl3N9dQlHw4 returns isOriginal = false

Comment: 1/2 Thanks for your feedback. Indeed my API doesn't work in this case. In fact for the video you sent, except for the intro which anybody could put at the start of its video, there is no mark that it is officially a YouTube original. I mean for [`iqKdEhx-dD4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqKdEhx-dD4) there is below the video the fields `Release date`, `Running time`, `Language` and `Rating` that can't be set on any YouTube video.

Comment: 2/2 Even the `YouTube Originals` watermark have different sizes on the thumbnails of [`Yl3N9dQlHw4`](https://img.youtube.com/vi/Yl3N9dQlHw4/maxresdefault.jpg) and [`iqKdEhx-dD4`](https://img.youtube.com/vi/iqKdEhx-dD4/maxresdefault.jpg). Even the intros are different on `iqKdEhx-dD4` `YouTube Originals` is written in black on a white background while on `Yl3N9dQlHw4` it's written in white on a red background.

Comment: I looked your code on github, you use following condition to check if it's original:
            $isOriginal = doesPathExist($json, 'engagementPanels/1/engagementPanelSectionListRenderer/content/structuredDescriptionContentRenderer/items/0/videoDescriptionHeaderRenderer/publishDate/simpleText');

I don't see where you are using the release date, running time, language, rating, ...

Comment: also I checked the page source for video Yl3N9dQlHw4, it contains the following text

`xtags=acont%3Doriginal`


looks like it means it's original

Comment: The long JSON path in my code checks the presence of a `Release date`. I will investigate if there are other ways in the source code of the webpage.

Comment: I dug and there is only `xtags=acont%3Doriginal` but it doesn't looks like what we are looking for as it is usually in `ytInitialData` JSON encoded JavaScript variable. Furthermore I agree that `xtags=acont%3Doriginal` is in `Yl3N9dQlHw4` source code but not in the one of `iqKdEhx-dD4`. Assuming that `Yl3N9dQlHw4` is a YouTube original, except listing every pattern (intro or thumbnail etc) to check if a given video has such a pattern, it doesn't seem that there is a perfect solution.

Comment: I spot checked a few non-original videos, none of them contains `xtags=acont%3Doriginal`.

Probably you can check both conditions, and if either one is met, the video is a YouTube original.

Comment: I forgot about this possibility (even if it doesn't look perfectly correct), [I have modified my commit accordingly](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/f89222305113c96ab03d63621f8140d4c9a801c6#diff-515c409ddb619da28c52829262e517f3d2ab4910aaa2ab60dd88e9064e0cfd4fR228-R233).